# VBA place two charts on one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can I place two different sheets on one page.
I create a chart with this code

```
'Create a chart
    Set cht = Worksheets("Dashboard").Shapes.AddChart2
    'Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2

With cht
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng 'Give chart some data
    .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked 'Determine the chart type
    .Chart.PlotBy = xlColumns
    .ScaleHeight 1.7, msoFalse
    .Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
    .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = Range("E1")
End With

Worksheets("Dashboard").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Name = "FalseCall"
Range("A1") = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Name
ActiveSheet.Shapes("FalseCall").Left = Range("A1").Left
ActiveSheet.Shapes("FalseCall").Top = Range("A1").Top
ActiveSheet.Shapes("FalseCall").Width = Range("A1:G1").Width
ActiveSheet.Shapes("FalseCall").Height = Range("A1:A26").Height
```

It will add a chart on sheet "Dashboard".

Next I want to add a new chart with another name on the same page on H1 with

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Name = "Ng"
```

The existing chart will be renamed with the name of the second Chart and moves to H1, instead of the new chart is getting that name and moving the H1

Answer (score 0):

It's not more complicated than repeating the steps with new ranges specified.

```
Sub InsertTwoCharts()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Dashboard")
    
    ' CHART 1
    ' range that chart will cover
    Dim ChtRng1 As Range
    Set ChtRng1 = ws.Range("A1:G26")
    
    ' chart data range
    Dim ChtData1 As Range
    Set ChtData1 = Worksheets("Whatever").Range("A1:E12") ' or whatever
    
    ' insert and modify the chart
    Dim cht1 As ChartObject
    Set cht1 = ws.Shapes.AddChart2
    With cht1
        .Name = "FalseCall"
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ChtData1, PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .Chart.SetElement msoElementLegendRight
        .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = ws.Range("E1").Value ' pick a worksheet and cell
        .Left = ChtRng1.Left
        .Top = ChtRng1.Top
        .Width = ChtRng1.Width
        .Height = ChtRng1.Height
    End With
    
    ' CHART 2
    ' range that chart will cover
    Dim ChtRng2 As Range
    Set ChtRng2 = ws.Range("H1:N26")
    
    ' chart data range
    Dim ChtData2 As Range
    Set ChtData2 = Worksheets("Whatever").Range("G1:K12") ' or whatever
    
    ' insert and modify the chart
    Dim cht2 As ChartObject
    Set cht2 = ws.Shapes.AddChart2
    With cht2
        .Name = "TrueCall"
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ChtData1, PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .Chart.SetElement msoElementLegendRight
        .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = ws.Range("H1").Value ' pick a worksheet and cell
        .Left = ChtRng2.Left
        .Top = ChtRng2.Top
        .Width = ChtRng2.Width
        .Height = ChtRng2.Height
    End With

End Sub
```